# Using sqlite under windows

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt, static-libraries

I'm developing an app with Qt and sqlite. I had no problems while I was working under Linux, but now I have to switch to Windows for a while, and i'm stuck with a simple question.

I've downloaded the sqlite source, and compiled it with Qt as a static library. As an output, I've got three files: `libsqlite.a`, `shell.o` and `sqlite3.o`. I strongly believe that the `libsqlite.a` is my static library.

Now, I want to use it in my project. In the project directory, I've created a folder called `sqlite`, and put the files inside of it.

After that, I'm trying to add the library to my project. In the `.pro` file, I add this:

```
LIBS += -L"/sqlite" -l"libsqlite"
```

However, I keep getting an error saying:

```
cannot find -llibsqlite
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"lib" prefix must be omitted.

Use the

```
-lsqlite
```

linker directive.

P.S.  Another viable option is including the SQLite's sources directly to your project. There's a SQLite "amalgamation" package (only `sqlite3.c` and `sqlite3.h` files).

Comment: Wow, that's not something that I would guess... I'll check it in the evening and tick your answer.

Comment: In fact Qt already includes SQLite.  If you want to use the Qt SQL API all you need is the SQLite driver plugin and it will work.  If not, then follow the above advice.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Though I had to add `$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_` before the folder path.